# prolog predicate logic(negation)

Tags: prolog

I have the following logical task:

*If David is interested in logic, then he will either enroll in the Logic course next semester, or he is lazy.
If David studied logic literature on his own, then he is interested in logic.
David studied logic literature on his own.
David is not lazy.*

This is how I presented it in prolog

```
a(X,Y):-d(X,Y).
not(b(X)):-d(X,_).
d(X,Y):-c(X,Y).
c(david,logic).
b(david).
```

where

a(X,Y) X will enroll in the next semester for classes on the course Y

b(X) X is not lazy

c(X,Y) X independently studied literature on Y

d(X,Y) X is interested in Y

and I seem to have written my program correctly, because the question is?-**a(david,logic)**  I get **true**

but this line confuses me: **not(b(X)):-d(X,_).**

As for me, it looks very strangely written. Tell me if I did something wrong

Comment: Could have chosen far more meaningful & helpful predicate and variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The clause `not(b(X)):-d(X,_).` is never used in your query, that is solved by the following subset:

```
a(X,Y):-d(X,Y).
d(X,Y):-c(X,Y).
c(david,logic).
```

Comment: I understand that it is not used anywhere. But let's say, if a similar negation is needed in some task (in the sense that it will affect the outcome of the task true or false), then how to describe it correctly?

Comment: I think you need something more complex than pure Prolog, see for instance https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/scasp.swinb